# Динамический/событийный вектор по растровому слою,как/чем?

Tags: python, графика

Есть необходимость на картинке (чертеж) отрисовывать линии (например - стрелки) и размеры (цифры) исходя из введенных данных.
В идеале подошел бы Excel/Calc,но не знаю,имеют ли они такие возможности,пусть и через макросы.
Простое решение для Excel мне известно: картинка на заднем плана,скрытая сетка и замороченное позиционирование содержимого ячеек.

Чем можно подобное реализовать и как?
зы:представляю браузер (для манипулирования данными) и ... какие библиотеки такое могут,хотя бы для Python?

Comment: Картинка в каком формате?

Comment: в любом,не принципиально

Comment: Ну собственно Windows(или для другой ОС)-приложение на любом языке, который позволяет создать окно, имеет средства создания интерфейса для ввода данных, и отрисовать картинку, стрелки/цифры. Си шарп, C++ c QT или другими библиотеками, Delphi, Java и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понял,нужна среда разработки (Visial IDE,пусть будет QT),где добавляются элементы/поля поверх растра и между которыми налаживается связь по событию?У Python существуют библиотеки,где к области (координатному звену) можно привязать линии и поля с цифрами?

Comment: Да, существуют, тот же PyQt, tkinter, kivy и т.д. но лучше пусть питонисты посоветуют.